# UITextField in UITableView: setting the first responder view of the table but we don't know its type (cell/header/footer)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a UITextField inside of a UITableViewCell, and I want to detect when a user begins typing inside of the UITextField. So I set the UITextFields delegate, but when that code runs, I get the warning 'setting the first responder view of the table but we don't know its type (cell/header/footer)' and the UITextField delegate methods dont get called. How can I properly get the UITextField methods to get called?

```
-(void)tableView:(id)view willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ((indexPath.section == 0) && (indexPath.row == 3)) {
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(friendCellTapped)];
        [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    }
    else if ((indexPath.section == 0) && (indexPath.row == 4)) {
        NSLog(@"im called");
        UITextField *tagBox = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 6, 225, 25)];
        [tagBox setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
        [tagBox setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
        tagBox.delegate = self;
        [cell addSubview:tagBox];
    }
    else {
        %orig;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code for how you configure the text view on the cell.

Comment: Can you add the whole method, usually the error you see is caused by the view not being added to the cell properly. Do you have some other view which is added as a direct subview of the table view?

Comment: Yep, I added it. And the UITextField is the only subview added to that cell

Comment: Are you adding anything outside of the cell though, directly to the table view?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before by creating a `UITextField` variable on my `UIViewController` class and setting it to the UITableViewCell's textfield in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I then set the delegate of my `UITextField` variable in `viewDidAppear:`.

Something like this:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.theTextField.delegate = self;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   //load custom cell

   self.theTextField = myCustomCell.cellTextField;

   return myCustomCell;
}
```

Then your UITextFieldDelegate methods should get called.

Comment: So I would have to create a custom uitableviewcell? Is there no way to do it without that?

Comment: That's the only way I know of to have a UITextField in a UITableViewCell

Comment: Well I _have_ a UITextField in a UITableView right now, just by adding it to the cell as a subview, it just doesnt call the delegate methods

Comment: Oh okay you added as a subview. Yeah I would recommend a custom UITableViewCell. Worked nicely for me.

Comment: Well, its a jailbreak tweak Im working on, so I have to work with the current cells that app uses :P